# ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 8 elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with many places and the details of their locations, such as latitude and longitude. What I need to do is to use map API to request json file of each place to get the nearby information around this place and then print out of them.

Everything works great until I try to create a function to repeat the same thing as the same thing I did to any place of my data.

python3
pandas

I can get what I want for anyone location separately, but my function didn't work.

I searched some threads about the same kind of question, such as change the columns or create the new dataframe first, but they didn't help.

```
def get_nearby_venues(names, prices, latitudes, longitudes):
    venues_list=[]

    for name, price, lat, lng in zip(names, prices, latitudes, longitudes):
        print(name)

        # construct urls from page 1 to page 5(the first page will be displayed when page_num=0)
        url_list = []
        for page_num in range(0, 5):
            urls = 'http://api.map.baidu.com/place/v2/search?query=公园$超市$美食$学校$医院$公交车站$银行$电影院&location={},{}&radius=1000&output=json&scope=2&page_size=20&page_num='+str(page_num)+'&ak=(API key)'.format(lat, lng)
            url_list.append(urls)

        # make request to get json content
        results_json_list = []
        for each in url_list:
            results_json = requests.get(each).json()['results']

            # merge all pages json content into one file and all of my location data is stored in it.
            results_json_list.extend(results_json)



        # I try to use the following code to print out but failed.


        # return only relevant information for each nearby venue
        for each_item in results_json_list:
            venues_list.append([
                name, 
                price,
                lat, 
                lng, 
                each_item.get('name'), 
                each_item.get('location').get('lat'), 
                each_item.get('location').get('lng'),
                each_item.get('detail_info').get('type')])

    nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in venues_list for item in sublist])
#     nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame(venues_list)

    nearby_venues.columns = ['Apartment', 
                             'Apartment Price',
                             'Apartment Latitude', 
                             'Apartment Longitude', 
                             'Venue', 
                             'Venue Latitude', 
                             'Venue Longitude', 
                             'Venue Category'] 

    return nearby_venues

# function code ends here


# dataframe data_venues is what I want to the results stored in for each location of my data and dataframe 'Data_map' is my previous dataframe which contains 'Name', 'Categories', 'Latitude',     'Longitude' columns of my data

data_venues = get_nearby_venues(names=Data_map['Name'],
                                prices=Data_map['Price'],
                                latitudes=Data_map['Latitude'],
                                longitudes=Data_map['Longitude']
                               )



ERROR MESSAGE code:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-9b269af7a350> in <module>
      8                                prices=Data_map.['Price'],
      9                                latitudes=Data_map['Latitude'],
---> 10                                longitudes=Data_map['Longitude']
     11                                )

<ipython-input-32-01b4632eb663> in get_nearby_venues(names, prices, latitudes, longitudes)
     44                              'Venue Latitude',
     45                              'Venue Longitude',
---> 46                              'Venue Category'] 
     47 
     48 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __setattr__(self, name, value)
   5078         try:
   5079             object.__getattribute__(self, name)
-> 5080             return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
   5081         except AttributeError:
   5082             pass

pandas/_libs/properties.pyx in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _set_axis(self, axis, labels)
    636 
    637     def _set_axis(self, axis, labels):
--> 638         self._data.set_axis(axis, labels)
    639         self._clear_item_cache()
    640 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in set_axis(self, axis, new_labels)
    153             raise ValueError(
    154                 'Length mismatch: Expected axis has {old} elements, new '
--> 155                 'values have {new} elements'.format(old=old_len, new=new_len))
    156 
    157         self.axes[axis] = new_labels

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 8 elements
```

Answer (score 0):

when a df is created **already** with a single column, you can NOT `df.columns = list of more columns`

**continued**

right after you got `nearby`
insert the following code, it will provide a guidance what is going on. But not to achieve exactly what you want.

```
nearby = nearby.rename(
    columns=dict( zip(
        [0,1,2,3], 
        ['Apartment','Apartment Price', 'Apartment Latitude', 'Apartment Longitude'])) 
) 
for coln in ['Venue','Venue Latitude','Venue Longitude','Venue Category']:
    nearby.insert(column=coln, loc=len(nearby.columns), value=np.nan)
```

the fundamental cause of the error is that, your new data, does **NOT** have the same amount of columns as your old data, that's why the old method works on the old data but not the new data.

Comment: for you specific case, `nearby_venues` is a df of a single column. right away, you cramped a list a 8 strings into `df.columns` properties. What your intention is `df.insert(list_columnNames)` (you need to google the proper syntax for `.insert()`, it is not the same across panda versions)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

You're right. Seems like code line:
*nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([item for sublist in venues_list for item in sublist])*
will transfer my data into only with one column dataframe. 
<img src="https://i.loli.net/2019/04/28/5cc5248de8cd3.png" width="200" height="100">
So I changed into the following code line:
    *nearby_venues = pd.DataFrame([venues_list])*
and it works for any place in my Data.
<img src="https://i.loli.net/2019/04/28/5cc524c07b738.png" width="200" height="100">
However, the same error still persists and I really don't know what to do. Cheers

Comment: your error is due to `nearby_venues.columns = list`. you should avoid that. try either `df.rename` or `df.insert`

Answer (score 0):

After changing the format of URL from:

```
for page_num in range(0, 5):
       urls = 'http://api.map.baidu.com/place/v2/search?query=公园$超市$美食$学校$医院$公交车站$银行$电影院&location={},{}&radius=1000&output=json&scope=2&page_size=20&page_num='+str(page_num)+'&ak=(API key)'.format(
            lat,
            lng)
```

into:

```
for num in range(0, 5):
    urls = 'http://api.map.baidu.com/place/v2/search?query=公园$超市$美食$学校$医院$公交车站$银行$电影院&location={},{}&radius=1000&output=json&scope=2&page_size=20&page_num={}&ak=(API key)'.format(
            lat, 
            lng,
            num)
```

it worked.

I have on idea why I can't ues the previous one to request json file, that's why it said *Expected axis has 0 elements*

@ugn Thanks for your insight :)